# Cannot parse a json string to date

Tags: java, json

I am trying to convert the following json string: `"Mon Apr 04 00:00:00 CEST 2016"` to a new date object by a `simpleDateFormat`. But i dont see why it wont work hope some one can help me.

```
String date = "Mon Apr 04 00:00:00 CEST 2016";
```

I get the following error:

> `(java.text.ParseException) java.text.ParseException: Unparseable
>   date: "Mon Apr 04 00:00:00 CEST 2016"`

```
public Date parseDate(String date) 
{ 
    try 
    {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
        Date returnDate = formatter.parse(date);
        return returnDate;
    }
    catch (ParseException e) 
    {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me.Just tried this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to parse with the locale:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 0):

> "EEE MMM ddHH:mm:ss z yyyy"

looks you forgot to put the space after `dd`:

```
"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"
```

Comment: Sorry that was a copy paste mistake but it still not fix the problem i have